# Usage example of boost::condition::timed_wait

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread, condition-variable

Does someone have an example of how to most easily use boost::condition::timed_wait? There are some threads on the topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259025/how-do-i-get-boostconditiontimed-wait-to-compile), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669995/what-does-boostcondition-variabletimed-wait-return-on-spurious-wakeups) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877032/boostcondition-variable-timed-wait-return-immediately), but none feature a working example. And boost doc is as usual quite sparse.

Comment: This seems well documented in boost and a timed wait on a condition variable is very common in a multithreaded environment.  What specifically are you looking for help with?

Comment: @Chad: Maybe I just missed the doc? All I found was [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref). That only contains an non timed sample, namely `while(!data_ready) { cond.wait(lock); }`. For timed, it only says _The duration overload of timed_wait is difficult to use correctly. The overload taking a predicate should be preferred in most cases._ I don't understand that though, nor this snippet: `while(!pred()) { if(!timed_wait(lock,abs_time)) { return pred(); } } return true;` What is pred() supposed to be?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Actually, I finally found a link with full example [here](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/condition-variable-spurious-wakes.html). With a bit of adapting, this seems to be the call.

```
boost::system_time const timeout=boost::get_system_time()+ boost::posix_time::milliseconds(35000);
boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(the_mutex);
if(the_condition_variable.timed_wait(lock,timeout,&CondFulfilled))
{
    <cond fulfilled code>
}
else
{
    <timeout code>
}
bool CondFulfilled() { ... }
```